# How to map TYPO3 frontend ajax to handler

Tags: ajax, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-extensions

How can I make an ajax POST from a frontend TYPO3 page to a function or class method in my extension?

I have been using Extension Builder which by default seems to build an MVC extension but my extension doesn't need to be MVC.

I can place a javascript ajax call on my page but how do I map this to my handler and what do I use for the url parameter in my ajax function?  Furthermore, how would I secure the url?

I am using TYPO3 v7.6

Answer (score 0):

In your custom extension call ajax like below.

**Javascript** for call Ajax

```
function callAjax(param)
{
    $.ajax({
        async: 'true',
        url: 'index.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            eID: "Ajax_call",
            id:pageId,
            param:{
                param1:value
            }
        },
        success:function (data) {
            if (data.succ == 1) {
                $("#ad-success").show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**localconf.php** file

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']['eID_include']['Ajax_call'] = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::extPath('extension_key').'Classes/Ajax/EidDispatcher.php';
```

**EidDispatcher.php** file.

```
<?php

namespace vendor\extension_key\Ajax;

class EidDispatcher
{
    /**
   * @var \array
   */
    protected $configuration;

    /**
   * @var \array
   */
    protected $bootstrap;

    /**
   * The main Method
   *
   * @return \string
   */
    public function run()
    {
        return $this->bootstrap->run('', $this->configuration);
    }

    /**
   * Initialize Extbase
   *
   * @param \array $TYPO3_CONF_VARS
   */
    public function __construct($TYPO3_CONF_VARS)
    {
        // $page = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::_GP('page');

        $ajaxRequest = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::_GP('tx_extension_key');

        // create bootstrap
        $this->bootstrap = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap();

        // get User
        $feUserObj = \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Utility\EidUtility::initFeUser();

        // set PID
        $pid = (\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::_GET('id')) ? \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::_GET('id') : 0;

        // Create and init Frontend
        $GLOBALS['TSFE'] = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(
            'TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Controller\TypoScriptFrontendController',
            $TYPO3_CONF_VARS,
            $pid,
            0,
            true
        );
        \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Utility\EidUtility::initLanguage();
        \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Utility\EidUtility::initTCA();
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->connectToDB();
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user = $feUserObj;
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->id = $pid;
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->determineId();
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->initTemplate();
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->getConfigArray();
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->settingLanguage();

        // Get Plugins TypoScript
        $TypoScriptService = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Service\TypoScriptService();
        $pluginConfiguration = $TypoScriptService->convertTypoScriptArrayToPlainArray(
            $GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->setup['plugin.']['tx_extension_key*emphasized text*.']
        );
        // Set configuration to call the plugin
        $this->configuration = array(
            'pluginName' => 'plugin_name',
            'vendorName' => 'vendor_name',
            'extensionName' => 'extension_name',
            'controller' => 'controller',
            'action' => 'action',
            'params' => $ajaxRequest['param'],
            'mvc' => array(
                'requestHandlers' => array(
                    'TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Web\FrontendRequestHandler' => 'TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Web\FrontendRequestHandler'
                )
            ),
            'settings' => $pluginConfiguration['settings'],
            'persistence' => array (
                'storagePid' => $pluginConfiguration['persistence']['storagePid']
            )
        );
    }
}
global $TYPO3_CONF_VARS;
// make instance of bootstrap and run
$eid = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(
    'vendor\ExtensionKey\Ajax\EidDispatcher',
    $TYPO3_CONF_VARS
);
echo $eid->run();
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply.  Which method is the ajax handler from which I can return my response? How can I do a POST to a custom url (I don't really want to go in to index.php with query string parameters)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to provide AJAX endpoints for the frontend in TYPO3 that I am aware of:

### eID

Plain and fast, but does not load a frontend context by default. Many developers have burnt themselves using it wrong.

I would not use it if I would want to do anything else than just plain, non-Extbase PHP because building the TYPO3-context "by hand" is error-prone and working ways have changed from version to version. Being able to control the bootstrapping provides possibilities for perfomance improvements, though, if you really need it.

### typeNum

gives you a standard frontend environment for your code. For an Extbase-plugin you would define another PAGE object in TypoScript with just your plugin's content on it:

```
ajaxPage = PAGE # call it whatever you want
ajaxPage {
   typeNum = 9787 # use a unique, unused typeNum
   10 < tt_content.list.20.yourextension_yourpluginname
   config {
     disableAllHeaderCode = 1
     additionalHeaders = Content-type:text/html # or application/json, or... 
     xhtml_cleaning = 0 
     admPanel = 0 # suppress Typo3 from adding anything unwanted
     debug = 0 # suppress Typo3 from adding anything unwanted
     no_cache = 1 # control if the output should be cachable
  }
}
```

To call your plugin via AJAX, you would add the page type to the URL.
In Fluid you would build it like that:

```
{f:uri.action(action: 'youraction', pageType: 9787)} # add controller=, pluginName=, extensionName= as needed
```

### EXT:typoscript_rendering

https://github.com/helhum/typoscript_rendering

An extension that saves you from the TypoScript-configuration in the typeNum-approach but keeps the advantages, especially for AJAX to Extbase-actions.

After writing a normal Extbase-plugin you can use the ViewHelper
https://github.com/helhum/typoscript_rendering/blob/master/Classes/ViewHelpers/Uri/AjaxActionViewHelper.php to get the AJAX URL for your Extbase action.

Example in Fluid:

```
xmlns:t="http://typo3.org/ns/Helhum/TyposcriptRendering/ViewHelpers" # ViewHelper namespace

{t:uri.ajaxAction(action: 'youraction')} # works just like the Fluid f:uri.ajax.action with the same parameters.
```

### Middlewares (TYPO3 v9+):

That's the way forward for me.

For example: In `EXT:<extension>/Configuration/RequestMiddlewares.php`:

```
<?php

return [
    'frontend' => [
        '<vendor>/<package>/json-middleware' => [
            'target' => \Vendor\Package\Http\MyJsonMiddleware::class,
            'after' => [
                'typo3/cms-frontend/site',
                // this gives TypoScript, routing and languageAspect. 
                // If you don't need that, you can build lightning-fast
                // routes (like eID) by adding the Middleware higher up
                // in the stack.
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

You can control any aspect of the HTTP response (for example client-side caching using E-Tag, access control, ...) then in your custom Middleware. I prefer to set up the Middleware as a dispatcher just dealing with the HTTP part and have it delegate the data generation to (non-Extbase) controller classes.
See [TYPO3 Middlewares documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/RequestLifeCycle/Middlewares.html)

Comment: "See TYPO3 Developer's answer as an example." There is only 1 answer and it is not by "TYPO3 Developer"

Comment: What would you recommend for more newer TYPO3 versions (e.g. >= v11)? Can this also be solved with middlewares?

Comment: Hi Sybille, I don't know what I was referring to. Yes, MiddleWares is what I use nowadays. I'll edit the answer